# My Fan Pc Spinning fast after updating linux kernel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, laptop, acpi

I tried updating from linux kernel 5.19 to 6.1.9

My laptop fan is usually not active when there are no applications, even when opening many applications, unless I do something heavy, but after I update to the new kernel 6.1.9 I don't open the fan application, it remains active.

Is it a bug? / normal?

Edit:

My Specs pc
CPU: Amd Ryzen 5500u
Ram: 8GB
DISK: 500gb SSD NVME
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
PC: MSI MODERN 14 b5m

I tried updating the kernel using this command

```bash
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.9/amd64/linux-headers-6.1.9-060109-generic_6.1.9-060109.202302010835_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.9/amd64/linux-headers-6.1.9-060109_6.1.9-060109.202302010835_all.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-6.1.9-060109-generic_6.1.9-060109.202302010835_amd64.deb

wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1.9/amd64/linux-modules-6.1.9-060109-generic_6.1.9-060109.202302010835_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: kernel 6.19 ? Do you mean 6.1.9 ?

Comment: Anything in dmesg regarding your sensor drivers ?

Comment: Are you sure you've updated just the kernel? Are you sure you're running the exact same tasks or e.g. browsing the exact same websites?

Comment: @MC68020 kernel linux 6.1.9-060109-generic

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov yes I'm sure it's because of the kernel, because before this it wasn't so noisy, it's noisy when I do heavy tasks, but in the latest kernel I don't do any tasks the fan is already noisy

Comment: @Freddy i already added it

Comment: Bios Update [E14DLAMS.111 (2023-01-30)](https://www.msi.com/Business-Productivity/Modern-14-B5SX/support?sub_product=Modern-14-B5M#bios), EC Firmware update [14DLEMS1.105
(2022-04-19)](https://www.msi.com/Business-Productivity/Modern-14-B5SX/support?sub_product=Modern-14-B5M#firmware). 
There's nothing in the readme's regarding fans, only "Improve system stability.", whatever that means. You need Windows to apply these updates.

Comment: Can you maybe edit the question and clarify "I don't open the fan application" - do you mean you don't open any applications that would cause heavy load? Does `top`/`htop` give any hint of a process that's eating up CPU time?

Comment: Dust could cause problems like this.  Could it be that you used to run 5.19 with a quiet fan, then a a few years you've re-setup the machine and upgraded the kernel?  In that case, perhaps dust has accumulated and you need to clean the inside of the machine.

Comment: now my pc is normal, maybe because ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support the latest kernel so it makes my pc fan noisy, now it's normal because i've downgraded to the old kernel, thank you very much everyone for the comments